# Javadoc only generates the Interface comments and not the class implementations

Tags: java, eclipse, documentation, javadoc

I am confused about something very basic when generating a Javadoc.

Lets say I have an interface:

```
/**
*Javadoc comment in interface
*
*/
public interface IOne{
    public Comparable[] meth();
}
```

Then I have a class:

```
public class ClassOne implemets IOne{
    /**
    *Javadoc comment in class
    *
    */
    public Comparable[] meth(){
        //implementation
    }
}
```

When I generate the Javadoc:

- Project > Generate Javadoc
- I point in the Javadoc command to the Javadoc exe
- I choose Public
- I choose a destination
- Finish

It generates and apparently correct HTML.

When I go to IOne the documentation for `meth()` says:

> Javadoc comment in class

But it says the exact same thing when I go to the method of the class in `meth()`.

Is this what it is supposed to do?

Where can I find/generate the `Javadoc comment in class`?

**UPDATE:**

This is because of the `@Override` before the comments. I'm reading as to where the override should be there or not.

Answer (score 3):

Use `{@inheritDoc}` to [merge](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/windows/javadoc.html#inheritingcomments) implementation and interface documentation.